# How to increase the size of physical memory in windows 7 32 bit OS

Tags: windows, windows-7

I have a total 4 Gb ram and I had installed a Virtual box and had assigned it 1.5 Gb memory. But now my applications in windows are reporting "running out of memory". So i changed the setting in Virtual Box to use 512mb of memory. But still the Task manager in Windows shows only 2Gb of physical memory.
I have tried a couple of ways mentioned to increase virtual memory in Advanced system property but that doesn't help either. So i want a way to increase the ram size allocated to windows.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778%28VS.85%29.aspx#physical_memory_limits_windows_7) says the Physical memory limit in Windows 7 Ultimate is 4Gb

Thanks

Comment: This isn't a programming question, it sounds like a question straight from VirtualBox's forums

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the help everyone. I googled yesterday and got a way to increase the size of physical ram through /3GB switch. Here is the method:

To enable the 3GB switch on Windows Vista™ or Windows 7:

1. Right-click Command Prompt in the Accessories program group of the Start menu. Click Run as Administrator.
2. At the command prompt, enter "bcdedit /set IncreaseUserVa 3072"
3. Restart the computer.

To disable the 3GB switch:

1. Right-click on Command Prompt in the Accessories program group of the Start menu. Click Run as Administrator.
2. At the command prompt, enter "bcdedit /deletevalue IncreaseUserVa"
3. Restart the computer.

This does not display the increased size in the task manager as it still shows 2GB but now when my applicationx crash they indicate the current memory usage as 3GB

Answer (score 0):

You may have 4GB of RAM, but usually 1-2GB of that is taken by things like the kernel and the graphics card, leaving you with 2GB "usable" RAM.